# MVC3 Data Annotation Dataformat issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, dataformat

I have an MVC2 C# .Net web app.  We are wanting one of our properties to always display with two decimal places: i.e.

```
.1 display as 0.10
1 display as 1.00
1.1 display as 1.10
1.21 display as 1.21
```

I have applied the following Data Annotations

```
[Display(Name = "Complexity/Scaling Factor")]
[DefaultValue(1.00)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a numeric value with up to two decimal places greater than zero.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$", 
    ErrorMessage = "Please enter a numeric value with up to two decimal places greater than zero.")]
public virtual double ComplexityFactor { get; set; }
```

...however the resulting properties are not displaying correctly.

```
2.1 displays as 2.1
1 displays as 1
```

Ideas?